# Brand new Acer Aspire V3-722G randomly restarts constantly

Tags: windows-8, acer-aspire

Yesterday my [Acer Aspire V3](http://www.acerstore.com.au/acer/ess/Aspire%20V3-772G%20Spec.pdf) arrived, but I have been having a lot of trouble with it.

Basically, it will suddenly restart every 5-10 minutes. It seems more likely to happen if I try run a couple things at the same time. Another thing that has happened a couple times is the screen has suddenly gone extremely distored (weird lines of random colours all over the place) and freezes.

I have a poor understanding of PC hardware and so on, but one thing that comes to mind is that I had the RAM upgraded to 32GB. Perhaps they botched putting the RAM in? I'm not experienced in this field but maybe that is an obvious place to look when a PC behaves in this particular way.

I've done every Windows Update I could find and checked all my drivers, etc. I've even done a factory reset but I get the same thing happening.

Any ideas? I can take a photo of the screen distortion when it happens again if that helps. All the details are in the PDF linked above. Of course I plan to contact Acer tonight, but I am hoping this is something common that has an easy fix I can do myself.

Comment: If someone suggested that you would have to pull it all apart, would you? You are best to RMA it and enjoy the warrantee realizing that defects happen. ;)

Comment: @CarlB The main reason I've asked this question is in case someone came along with something like 'oh that's a known issue with that model, just install X and run Y and it should fix it'.

Answer (score 0):

This could be memory related failure. If you can access memory modules, you can try removing them one by one. If one of the modules is bad, the laptop will run properly when you remove this module.